# Enable FDF Support for PHP Version 5.6.24

Tags: php, fdf

How to Enable FDF Support for PHP Version 5.6.24?

I have a Version before that is PHP Version 5.2.17.
Which has the FDF Support working.

**fdf**

**FDF Support:  enabled**

**FdfTk Version:    5.0**

But when I upgrade the version to PHP Version 5.6.24. It is not working.
I have all the files in the Place.

1. In **PHP.ini**, I added the line. **extension=php_fdf.dll**
2. in **PHP/ext** folder I have the file in place **php_fdf.dll**
3. in **PHP/** folder I have the file in place **fdftk.dll**

I have **Windows server 2008 r**2 and **IIS 7**.
I have restart the server and IIS many time, but still the fdf support is not enabled.

But still it not come in the phpinfo page.

Please guide me , what I have to do, to make it work.

Comment: Not sure if you followed the [installation instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/fdf.setup.php). Among other details: *You need the FDF toolkit SDK available from Adobe. [...] This extension is considered unmaintained and dead. [...] This extension is no longer bundled with PHP as of PHP 5.3.0.*

Answer (score 0):

The extensions are compiled for every PHP version. So of you have 5.2 before you can't run the same DLLs with PHP 5.5. Then you need newer DLLs for the right version in you case PHP 5.5.

I hope you get a newer version otherwise you have to look for a new solution.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you can do with FDF you can also do with XFDF, the XML flavor of FDF. Because it's XML, you won't need a special library to work with it and can use the most current version of PHP.

You can read the XFDF Specification here...
https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xml/XFDF_Spec_3.0.pdf